# Databinding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I wanted to create a control with a TextBox and to bind **TextBox.Text** property with my own Dependency Property **TextProp**. (Some kind of experiment) However, the binding does not work! What I am doing wrong?

XAML:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding TextProp}" x:Name="textb"/>
    </UserControl>
```

C#:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextProp = "fwef";
        }

        public string TextProp
        {
            get { return ( string )GetValue(TextPropProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextPropProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextPropProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TextProp",typeof( string ),typeof(UserControl1));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to set [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx), from where Binding could get actual property...

Try one of the following:

**C#**

```
public UserControl1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   TextProp = "fwef";
   DataContext = this;
}
```

**Or**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding TextProp}" x:Name="textb"/>
    </UserControl>
```

**Or 2**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
        <TextBox DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestory, AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl}}} Text="{Binding TextProp}" x:Name="textb"/>
</UserControl>
```

I wrote this from head, hope I didn't make any typo here.

Hope it helps,

Cheers.